# Using search server service layer vs database layer for finding entities

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, elasticsearch

If you have both a search api set up (using Elasticsearch) and a repository layer (Spring JDBC) would you use the search api always no matter how trivial the queries is? It is much more flexible than the repository version, but it is a bit slower. For example: Would you use the search api to get all cars by some creators name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have a repository and ES sitting next to eachother with some overlapping query-functionality

The strength of a repository (if we're speaking about a DDD repository that is) is to provide an interface for the client, without it having to know how you actually do the queries in the backend.

Say a repo implements: 
`getById(id)`
`getByName(name)`
`getByExample(JsonExample)`
`getByFullText(text)`

I would be perfectly fine to implement `getById` (and perhaps `getByName`) using your primary data-store. (mysql , mongoDB, couchbase or whatever you use to feed ES)

At the same time `getByFullText(text)` would definitely be implemented by ES, and `getByExample(JsonExample)` probably as well.

The point is that by bringing the implementation behind the repository-abstraction the rest of your application couldn't/shouldn't care less about how you actually implemented it.

For you this means, just go with what feels natural (`get all cars by some creators name` would work with both ES and your primary datastore presumably) If down the road you've got a real (performance or whatever) reason to switch, it's just a single line of code presumably in your repository implementation.

BTW: The notion of having multiple different datastores serve your queries is known as: [Polyglot Persistance.](http://martinfowler.com/articles/nosql-intro.pdf)

Comment: Ah, right so you would not create a "search service" on the service layer but instead move it behind the repository abstraction?

Comment: However, if this is the case I got some questions of how to change my code. Right now I have some classes such as SearchContext, and SearchResponse, would I have to change the names of these in order to keep the abstraction of a search server? Or can I still return these? Basically, is it bad to keep some of the search classes/terms even though it is handled through the repository.

Comment: For the given example: 'get all cars by creator name' , I'd indeed have the search implementation behind the repository abstraction. This is not to say that there' isn't ever a use for a separate searchservice. (i.e: for really search-specific stuff, like typeahead/suggest, highlighting, faceting, etc.) So please don't take my anwser as never wanting a seperate searchservice. It just depends on what makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. It was an interesting answer. I have not thought of mixing different data stores before.

Comment: I don't see why you can't keep the classnames. As long as for you (you coworkers ) it's apparent Searchresponse may come from a primary datastore, ES, etc.

Comment: Glad it helped. Another often used pattern is to only index stuff in ES you're actually searching for in ES and don't store anything else. Instead use a 2-stage fetch: i.e: search in ES, and given the returned ids, do a multi-key lookup in your primary datastore to retrieve the needed data. This keeps ES lean, while using your primary datastore (especially when using a KV-store) to do what it does best: looking up data by key. It's up to you, but with the above answer hopefully it's clear this is 'just' another implementation sitting behind the repository abstraction.